# Sequelize: Querying where I use foreignKey instead of as

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

So I'm having some trouble getting the query results I'm looking for. In terms of models I have

```
models.UserRole = sequelize.define('userrole', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    permissions: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
        defaultValue: []
    }
});

models.User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    ...
});

models.User.belongsTo(models.UserRole, {foreignKey: 'role'});
```

And I used *foreignKey* instead of *as* because I wanted the field to be called **role** exactly and not what Sequelize was changing it to (**roleName**).

Anyway, I'm now trying to query and include the permissions along with the selected user, so I use

```
    models.User.findById(id, {
        attributes: ['id','role'],
        include: [{
            model: models.UserRole,
            attributes: ['name', 'permissions']
        }]
    })
```

And it works, but it retrieves them on the field **userrole** and looks like this

```
{"id":"id-here","role":"admin","userrole":{"name":"admin", "permissions":["p1","p2",..]}}
```

So finally, my question is how do I make it so that the stuff it retrieves from the UserRole model is retrieved under the key "role" instead? So it looks like

```
{"id":"id-here","role":{"name":"admin", "permissions":["p1","p2",..]}}
```